# Find closest, following numbers in two vectors

Tags: r, sorting, vector

This question doesn't seem to have been solved in `R` yet. So, given e.g.

```
a <- c(20, 104, 380, 388)
b <- c(16, 38, 108, 130, 200, 222, 291, 314, 384, 406, 476, 498, 568, 591)
```

how do I find those numbers in `b` that follow those in `a`? The solution here, thus, should be `[38 108 384 406]`.

Note that `a` and `b` can vary in length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 b[colSums(sapply(a,">",b))+1]
[1]  38 108 384 406
```

You can also think of:

```
b[as.numeric(cut(a,b))+1]
[1]  38 108 384 406
```

Comment: While this works, it has to be stressed that it's very inefficient from an algorithmic point of view, since it involves a comparison between each element of `b` to each element of `a`.

Answer (score 5):

This makes use of the `findInterval` function:

```
b[findInterval(a, b)+1]
#### [1]  38 108 384 406
```

This (and maybe some of the others solutions suggested here) needs that you previously have your `b` vector sorted.

You can use the argument `left.open` to decide what behaviour you want when the numbers are equal.

Comment: This is the fastest solution given the example.

Comment: and in general it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Through for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(a)){
  c[i]<-b[which (b>=a[i])[1]]
}
> c
[1]  38 108 384 406
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(a, function(x) min(b[b > x]))
[1]  38 108 384 406
```